# Line Flux Ratios in Active galaxies

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, active-galaxy, spectrometry

Good day to everyone.

I wanted to know what is the importance of estimation of line flux ratios in active galaxies? What does it help in characterizing?

As in Lyman $\alpha /$Carbon IV, or Mg II$/$Carbon IV, or Carbon III$/$Carbon IV

Do you have any references about this? Kindly do share.

Comment: Hi, I found [this review](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev.astro.45.051806.110546) by Luis Ho very useful. If you have not already, start with a book. [An Introduction to Active Galactic Nuclei](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Cambridge/frames.html) by Bradley Peterson is a great book.